# Thumbnail gallery that loads image description and full size on same page on click

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress, gallery, thumbnails

I want to create [something like this](http://www.thekitchen.org/auction2010/#artwork).

Where do I get started with the javascript? Also, is it possible to customize something like this with the Nextgen Gallery plugin or another Wordpress plugin?

Comment: I think this question would be a better suited to webmasters. Also, you might try googling for “javascript photo gallery”.

Comment: If you've got a more specific question (like, for example “[how do I change an image with JavaScript](http://www.google.ca/search?q=how+do+I+change+an+image+with+JavaScript+site%3Astackoverflow.com)?”), please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two things:

1. A data `Object` that maps the thumbnail `src` value (or any other identifer) to the required URL and description Strings.
2. Some `Event` handler for the thumbnails that get the respective entries in the data `Object` and set the highlight `img` `Node`'s `src` attribute as well as the description text.

---

So, let's say this is your data `Object`:

```
var data = {
    <src>: {
        "url": <url for the large image> ,
        "text": <description for the large image>
    } ,
    <another src>:  {
        //..
    }
}
```

---

Now, you just have to get the `src` of the thumbnail `img` `Node` that raised the `Event` and get its respective entry in the data `Object`,

```
var img = /* the reference to the img Node that raised the event */ ;
var src = img.getAttribute("src") ;

var entry = data[src] ;
var url = entry.url , text = url.text ;
```

; then you simply have to change the `src` attribute of the large `img` `Node` and the text content of the `Node` containing the description.
You could also do the same thing using the `id` attribute.

HTH